# Unable to populate drop-down menu through AJAX call in IE-9

Tags: javascript, ajax

Through the AJAX call I am able to see returned data in httpxml.responseText returned through json encoded object. The code is working well in chrome to populate a drop down menu, but the same is not working in IE-9. My code is given below:

```
function stateChanged(){
    if(httpxml.readyState==4){

        alert(httpxml.responseText);
        var myarray = JSON.parse(httpxml.responseText);

        // Remove the options from 2nd dropdown list 
        for(j=document.myform.rgrade.options.length-1;j>=0;j--){
            document.myform.rgrade.remove(j);
        }

        for (i=0;i<myarray.data.length;i++){
            var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
            optn.text = myarray.data[i].descp;          
            optn.value = myarray.data[i].grade; 
            document.myform.rgrade.options.add(optn);
        } 
    }
}
```